# Naming volumes in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  database1:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/volume1:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network

  database2:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database2
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/volume2:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network

volumes:
  volume1:
    name: vol1
  volume2:
    name: vol2

networks:
  test_network:
    driver: bridge
```

When using `docker volume ls` I get the following:
[image]

How do I get the volumes to be named as `vol1` and `vol2` as indicated in the docker-compose?
I have noticed that if the volumes are not saved in relative path they are named correctly, but I require them to be saved in the `volumes` folder. I am using wsl on Windows.

Comment: The `mongo` image has a `VOLUME` declaration that creates a second anonymous volume mounted on `/data/configdb`, and that's what you're seeing here.  The bind mounts don't use the top-level Compose `volumes:` block and don't show up in `docker volume ls` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using your volumes in your `services` configuration. Instead of:

```
services:
  database1:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/volume1:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network

  database2:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database2
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/volume2:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network
```

You need to write:

```
services:
  database1:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database1
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - volume1:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network

  database2:
    image: mongo:6
    container_name: database2
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - volume2:/data/db
    networks:
      - test_network
```

That is, you need to reference the volumes named in your `volumes` section if you want to use them. Your existing configuration is bind-mounting a local directory rather than using a docker volume.

Comment: I understand. My confusion seems to come from thinking that the volume in my local was created in the same path containing the docker-compose, that's why I used relative paths. Thank you very much for the clarification.